# Python numpy type decimal places

Tags: python, types, numpy, decimal

I was wondering if there is a type in Numpy that allows numbers with around 20 decimal places, besides the type "decimal".

If not, do you have a suggestion to achieve the speed I would get performing calculations, say as when using floats?

Thanks,

Blaise

Comment: Is it a requirement that you don't encounter any floating point error?

Comment: `np.float64` has about 15 decimal places. If that is not enough, some platforms (anything not Windows running on 64bit HW and OS) may allow for a `np.float96` (19 decimal places) or a `np.float128` (33 decimal places).

Answer (score 1):

mpmath at https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/

> *mpmath* is a pure-Python library for multiprecision floating-point arithmetic. It provides an extensive set of transcendental functions,
>   unlimited exponent sizes, complex numbers, interval arithmetic,
>   numerical integration and differentiation, root-finding, linear
>   algebra, and much more. Almost any calculation can be performed just
>   as well at 10-digit or 1000-digit precision, and in many cases
>   *mpmath* implements asymptotically fast algorithms that scale well for extremely high precision work. *mpmath* internally uses Python's
>   builtin long integers by default, but automatically switches to
>   GMP/MPIR for much faster high-precision arithmetic if *gmpy* is
>   installed or if *mpmath* is imported from within Sage.